# Keyboard Module in a while loop

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, keyboard

```
import keyboard
while True:
    x = keyboard.add_hotkey("ctrl+alt+p", lambda: print("CTRL+ALT+P Pressed!"))
    if x == True:
        break()

#2nd way
import keyboard
while True:
    x = keyboard.add_hotkey("ctrl+alt+p", lambda: print("CTRL+ALT+P Pressed!"))
    break`
```

So the problem is with the loop. If ı put the break statement as ı did in the "2nd way", it just stops the code as expected and I cant execute the code as ı want. If ı do it with the if statement, the code works, but it spams the "CTRL+ALT+P Pressed!" message till I stop. How can I make it stop after 1 message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conventional way is using `keyboard.is_pressed` instead of `keyboard.add_hotkey`:

```
import keyboard

while True:
    x = keyboard.is_pressed("ctrl+alt+p")
    if x == True:
        print("CTRL+ALT+P Pressed!")
        break
```

---

In case we must use `keyboard.add_hotkey`, we have to pass the information that the key was pressed from the triggered method to the while loop.
We can't use an anonymous lambda method - use standard method instead.
We also have to execute `keyboard.add_hotkey` once before the loop.

We may use `x` as global variable:

```
import keyboard

def ctrl_alt_p_pressed():
    global x
    print("CTRL+ALT+P Pressed!")
    x = True

keyboard.add_hotkey("ctrl+alt+p", ctrl_alt_p_pressed)  # Execute ctrl_alt_p_pressed method when the key is pressed.

x = False

while True:
    if x == True:
        break
```

---

If we don't want to use global variables, we may pass `x` as an argument to the method `ctrl_alt_p_pressed`.
We may pass x as a of type list - we choose the list data type because list is passed by reference (updating the list inside the method, updates the list which passed as argument to the method).

```
import keyboard

def ctrl_alt_p_pressed(is_pressed_list):
    print("CTRL+ALT+P Pressed!")
    is_pressed_list.append(True)  # Append True to the list (to x).   

x = []
keyboard.add_hotkey("ctrl+alt+p", ctrl_alt_p_pressed, args=(x,))  # Execute ctrl_alt_p_pressed method with x as argument.

while True:
    if x:  # If list x is not empty
        break
```